# How can I apply this function to all the xml documents of a directory?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have this function:

```
def parse(filename):
    tweets=[]
    with open(filename,'r') as filename:
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for document in root.iter('document'):
            txt=document.text
            txt=txt.replace("![CDATA[",'')
            txt=txt.replace("]]",'')
            txt=txt.strip()
            tweets.append(document.text)
    return ' '.join(tweets)
```

Which parse the content of an xml document. How can I apply it to all the xml documents inside a directory and return them into a nested list:

`[[content xml doc 1], [content xml doc 2],...,[content xml doc n]]`

I tried this:

```
for pathname in glob.glob(os.path.join('../dir', '*.xml')):
    with open(pathname, 'r') as xmlfile:
        filename = os.path.basename(pathname)
```

However, it is not returning anything. Could anybody explain how to do this correctly?.

Comment: Are you sure you got the directory right? That looks like it should work.

Comment: Yes, its the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) which yields `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)` tuples recursively walking the directory:

```
for parent, directories, files in os.walk('dir'):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith('.xml'):
            continue
        pathname = os.path.join(parent, filename)
        try:
            parse(pathanme)
        except ET.ParseError:
            # Skip invalid xml
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a number of different files in different formats... How can I do the `*.xml` part?

Comment: @alonsopg, You can use `str.endswith` to check filename extension. I added `if ...: continue` to the code.

Comment: Thanks... but this is also not doing anything it is not returning nothing

Comment: @alonsopg, Change `dir` in `os.walk('dir')` according to your directory structure. `os.walkdir('.')` if you want to traverse current directory.

Comment: Thanks!... I got: `ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0`

Comment: I suspect that the xml are not well formed... however when I run the parse function over a single document it works... What can I do?

Comment: @alonsopg, `try ... except ...` to filter out malformed xml files.

Comment: Could you provide the answer edit just to accept the answer?

Comment: @alonsopg, Which part? `try .. except ..` ? I don't know which exception `parse` raise. So I can't. (Of course, I can use `except:`. But it's not a good style)

Comment: parse is raising: `ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0`

Comment: @alonsopg, Do you mean `lxml.etree.ParseError`.? or `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError` or another?

Comment: Well I am using: `xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

Comment: @alonsopg, I added `try .. except ..` to the code accordingly. Also removed `with open(...)` because it's done inside `parse`.

Comment: @alonsopg, `with open(..) as filename` is also redundant because `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse` accept both filename / file object as a parameter.